# XCTAssertEqual with Optional (not Equatable)

Tags: unit-testing, swift

I would like to make the following in assertion:

```
XCTAssertEqual(sut.dataSource?.delegate, userInterface, "Data source's delegate should be the user interface")
```

The properties `dataSource` and `delegate` are Optionals. I tried unwrapping them with `let` assignments, but it essentially boils down to either

```
Generic parameter 'T' cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type 'FetchedResultsControllerDataSourceDelegate'
```

or

```
Type 'FetchedResultsControllerDataSourceDelegate?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
```

What can I do to assert that the optional relationships are properly set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that "equal" compares values. `NSFetchedResultsControllerDataSourceDelegate` doesn't conform `Equatable` so it not possible to compare its values. You should compare its identity with with "identical to `===`" operator.

```
XCTAssertTrue(sut.dataSource?.delegate === userInterface, "Data source's delegate should be the user interface")
```

Comment: This caused a "'FetchedResultsControllerDataSourceDelegate' is not identical to 'AnyObject'". But I found out, that I need the `@objc` annotation on that protocol and then it works. Some things are still a mystery to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah okay.. I think I figured it out. I need the `@objc` annotation on the protocol because otherwise I'm comparing a pure Swift thing to a `UIViewController` which comes from the ObjC world and thus they can't be compared. Correct?

Comment: `@objc` for protocols says that only classes can conform the protocol.  So its safe for compiler to assume that `===` can be used for instances of type that conforms to such protocol.